# How to get a column from numpy arrays as a column not as a list?

Tags: python, numpy, multiple-columns

I want to get a column from a numpy array. Unfortunately when you slice the array, it gives you a list not a 2D array. What is the best way to do that ?

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

b = a[:, 1]
```

Here if we get the shape of 'b' (np.shape(b)), we would get (2,)

Comment: Your `b` is not a list!  A list doesn't have a `shape` attribute.  Indexing with a scalar reduces the dimension by 1.  That's well documented basic indexing.

Comment: You are right on that. I made a mistake.

Comment: Or simply use `b = a[:, [1]]`  which would give a 2D array instead of 1D. Because using `[1]` would be interpreted as a sequence instead of as a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you slice an a 2D array to a 1D array you obtain an array not a list.

FOr example,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(2,10)
a[0,:]
```

Output:

```
array([0.66697982, 0.60344488, 0.42005315, 0.11533043, 0.83256096,
       0.45661915, 0.81686457, 0.42709124, 0.7143827 , 0.78530728])
```

If you want to make this last array 2D one option that you have is to expand the axis:

```
a[0,:][:,np.newaxis]
```

Output:

```
array([[0.66697982],
       [0.60344488],
       [0.42005315],
       [0.11533043],
       [0.83256096],
       [0.45661915],
       [0.81686457],
       [0.42709124],
       [0.7143827 ],
       [0.78530728]])
```

Which is 2D.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In numpy you can get a column `i` by doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
your_array = np.random.randn(6,3)

i = 1

a=your_array[:, i:i+1]
```

This will give a view of rank 2 to the array `a`. The output will give the column 2 of the 2D array `your_array`

Comment: This one is also true. But I don't know which answer is more pythonian.

Comment: Yes, I agree with both the answers. But, I think this is a shorter version. You do not need to execute one more operation of `np.newaxis`. You directly get a 2-D array.

Comment: Two alternatives are equally `pythonic` is they both run - and especially if the speed is comparable.  Using a slice, `newaxis` or `reshape` are equally good.

Comment: It could be argued that getting a 1d array when selecting a column is the most idiomatic `numpy` thing.  Sure, there are times when you need a (n,1) array, such as when broadcasting with a (m,) array to produce (n,m).  Adding that `newaxis` on the fly as needed is perfectly good `numpy` style.